# Can I replace a single piece of aluminum siding?

Tags: siding

I bent the bottom piece of aluminum siding while reroofing a deck to install the roof to wall flashing. I have replacement pieces of the siding on hand. Is it possible to replace just the bottom piece of the siding? I can't figure out how to go about interlocking the new piece with the top piece because the hook is rigid.

Thanks

Comment: I've used a siding removal tool on vinyl siding in the past, but don't know how that would work on aluminum siding.  Google "siding removal tool" to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I came upon the tool in my search also but all the sites of using it are regarding vinyl. I imagine using the tool will bend the hook of the top piece, then I would take off the bottom piece and nail the new piece in. At this point, how would I hook the top piece back onto the bottom piece?

Comment: This video may help. https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=aluminum+siding+removal+tool&cvid=68954fbbfac94b26ae5d3c132636a99a&aqs=edge.0.0l3.16590j0j1&pglt=43&PC=U531&ru=%2fsearch%3fq%3daluminum%2bsiding%2bremoval%2btool%26cvid%3d68954fbbfac94b26ae5d3c132636a99a%26aqs%3dedge.0.0l3.16590j0j1%26pglt%3d43%26FORM%3dANNTA1%26PC%3dU531&view=detail&mmscn=vwrc&mid=5FBBB47B6163C2B5D55A5FBBB47B6163C2B5D55A&FORM=WRVORC

Comment: @r13 He nailed through both pieces of the siding. That'll be an option. I'm wondering if it's possible to hook both pieces together so it wouldn't look repaired.

Comment: I would do as shown, then try to patch and paint to hide the nail head.

Answer (score 3):

The sketch might say it all.

To clarify cutting the top off of the replacement piece: Cut it so the flat is as tall as possible. I have run my knife in the groove, and scored the deepest part of the groove. Flex the top edge a little after you score it twice, maybe 3 times and the top nail flange will break free, with the top edge nice and straight.

This will make it easy to slip in place and it will look like it never was damaged. Place the 3 pop rivets within a 1/4" of the upper piece, closer the better. That way they will be hidden as much as possible.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Interesting approach and one I would have never come up with! Distinct advantage to vinyl siding: it's flexible...